# Getting the active time of a Windows Machine in a given time frame

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to see if I can get the total time I am spending on my system in a given time frame.
Example: From 9 am to 9 pm, I should identify the time my machine is Locked, the time my machine is in Sleep mode, and the time my Machine is active.

I am able to get it from the last boot time, but what if I don't shutdown my system for a couple of days? Will I be able to get the Active Time I am spending on my Machine?

Also is there a way where I can get the time I am spending on an application? Example: I have Teams, Browser-Chrome, and an IDE installed. Can I get the time I am spending on an application in a given time frame?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. Written in Autoit ([www.autoitscript.com](http://www.autoitscript.com))
Of course you could extend this by checking the active Window title, getting the corresponding process and then count the amount of time spent on that specific application and so. This is just a start.

```
; workstation idle logger for windows
; Functions : IsWorkStationLocked() and IsScreenSaverRunning()
;

#include <Date.au3>

DllOpen("user32.dll")

$actiondate =  _NowCalc()
$timehaspastmin = 0
$timehaspasthour =0
$tmpString1=0
$tmpString2=0
$prediction="was working for"

While 1

        $actiontrigger = False

    $file = FileOpen("lockstatus.txt", 1)
    If $file = -1 Then
        MsgBox(0, "Error", "Unable to open file.")
        Exit
    EndIf

    $tmpString1=IsWorkStationLocked()
    $tmpString2=IsScreenSaverRunning()

    Sleep(10000)

    if $tmpString1 <> IsWorkStationLocked() Then
        $actiontrigger = True

    EndIf

    if  $tmpString2 <> IsScreenSaverRunning() Then
        $actiontrigger = True

    EndIf

    if $actiontrigger = True Then
        $timehaspastsec = _Datediff ( 's' , $actiondate , _NowCalc())
        $timehaspastmin = Round($timehaspastsec / 60,1)
        $timehaspasthour = Round($timehaspastmin /60,1)

        select
            case $timehaspasthour >= 1
                $timetype="hour(s)"
                $timehaspast=$timehaspasthour
            case $timehaspastmin >= 1
                $timetype="minute(s)"
                $timehaspast=$timehaspastmin
            case Else
                $timetype="second(s)"
                $timehaspast=$timehaspastsec
        EndSelect

        select
        case IsScreenSaverRunning() = False and IsWorkStationLocked() = False
            $prediction = "was away for"
        case IsScreenSaverRunning() = True and IsWorkStationLocked() = False
            $prediction = "was working for"
        case IsScreenSaverRunning() = True and IsWorkStationLocked() = True
            $prediction = "(really idle now) was watching my screen for "
        case IsScreenSaverRunning() = False and IsWorkStationLocked() = True
            $prediction = "was working for"
        EndSelect

        $outputstring =  _NowCalc() & " - " & "scrsaver=" & IsScreenSaverRunning() & ",Locked=" & IsWorkStationLocked() & ", " & $prediction & " " & $timehaspast & " " & $timetype & @CRLF
        FileWrite($file , $outputstring )
        ConsoleWrite ( $outputstring)
        $actiondate =  _NowCalc()
    EndIf

    FileClose($file)
WEnd

Func IsWorkStationLocked()
    Local $Desktop, $Return

    $Return = DllCall("user32.dll", "long", "OpenDesktopA", "str", "Default", "dword", 0, "ubyte", 0, "dword", 0x100)
    $Desktop = $Return[0]

    If $Desktop = 0 Then
        Return True
    EndIf

    $Return = DllCall("user32.dll", "long", "SwitchDesktop", "dword", $Desktop)
    DllCall("user32.dll", "long", "CloseDesktop", "dword", $Desktop)

    If $Return[0] = 0 Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    EndIf
EndFunc

Func IsScreenSaverRunning()
    Local $Desktop, $Return, $Result

    $Result = DllStructCreate("uint")
    $Return = DllCall("user32.dll", "ubyte", "SystemParametersInfoA", "uint", 0x72, "uint", 0, "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($Result), "uint", 0)
    If $Return[0] = 0 Then Return SetError( 0, False)

    Return DllStructGetData($Result, 1) <> 0
EndFunc
```

Comment: the autoit script looks fab. I was trying to identify each and every inbuilt function you have used and map it to Powershell. Can I Please know if there are some PowerShell functions that will deliver the same functionality?

Comment: @AdityaCh : Powershell uses the windows dlls and cmdlet methods are just wrappers for the window dlls.  You can always write your own cmdlets taking the above code.